# Error Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I start spring boot.. this is error message...I do not know what it is caused

```
2017-06-04 13:36:50.139  INFO 27571 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AppConfig               : Starting AppConfig on maciek-CX70-2PF with PID 27571 (/home/maciek/Desktop/spring/demo/target/classes started by maciek in /home/maciek/Desktop/spring/demo)
2017-06-04 13:36:50.140  INFO 27571 --- [           main] com.example.demo.AppConfig               : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-06-04 13:36:50.175  INFO 27571 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@74a10858: startup date [Sun Jun 04 13:36:50 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-06-04 13:36:50.242  WARN 27571 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.demo.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
2017-06-04 13:36:50.245 ERROR 27571 --- [           main] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Destroy method on bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.internalCachingMetadataReaderFactory' threw an exception

java.lang.IllegalStateException: ApplicationEventMulticaster not initialized - call 'refresh' before multicasting events via the context: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@74a10858: startup date [Sun Jun 04 13:36:50 CEST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getApplicationEventMulticaster(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.ApplicationListenerDetector.postProcessBeforeDestruction(ApplicationListenerDetector.java:97) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DisposableBeanAdapter.destroy(DisposableBeanAdapter.java:253) ~[spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroyBean(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:578) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:554) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingleton(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:961) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.destroySingletons(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:523) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.destroySingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:968) [spring-beans-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.destroyBeans(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1033) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:555) [spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.AppConfig.main(AppConfig.java:23) [classes/:na]

2017-06-04 13:36:50.253 ERROR 27571 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to parse configuration class [com.example.demo.AppConfig]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:181) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:308) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:228) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:93) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:686) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:524) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:737) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:370) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:314) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1162) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1151) [spring-boot-1.5.3.RELEASE.jar:1.5.3.RELEASE]
    at com.example.demo.AppConfig.main(AppConfig.java:23) [classes/:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect annotated methods on class org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:163) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.retrieveBeanMethodMetadata(ConfigurationClassParser.java:380) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:314) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:245) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:198) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:167) ~[spring-context-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 12 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContext
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.core.type.StandardAnnotationMetadata.getAnnotatedMethods(StandardAnnotationMetadata.java:152) ~[spring-core-4.3.8.RELEASE.jar:4.3.8.RELEASE]
    ... 17 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContext
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    ... 21 common frames omitted


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Build Maven file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <properties>
        <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
        <m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>/</m2eclipse.wtp.contextRoot>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Compile -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Provided -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <useSystemClassLoader>false</useSystemClassLoader>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

And config class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.builder.SpringApplicationBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.web.support.SpringBootServletInitializer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;


@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")
public class AppConfig extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(AppConfig.class);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }


}
```

I use spring boot and resolver jstl. My version spring boot is 1.5.3 RELEASE.

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix: .jsp
```

What could be wrong?

Comment: Are you trying to create a deployable war file ? Have a look at this link: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html

Comment: Thanks . It works :D

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced with the same issue and the root cause was related to missing dependency. The issue was not related to Spring boot starter. So, I have simply tried to add one more dependency which can work fine with your JSTL

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Change main method like this.**

```
@SpringBootApplication 
@ComponentScan("com.example.demo")

public class AppConfig {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(AppConfig.class, args);
    }}
```